# how to update part of a text in database record?

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

I'd like to update my URL in my WordPress database.

So in my wp_posts table inside the post_content I'd like to update every instance of http://example.com to https://example.com

How can I replace all the values at once?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UPDATE` and [`REPLACE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace).

```
UPDATE
   wp_posts
SET
   post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'http://example.com','https://example.com');
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [wp cli](https://wp-cli.org/) command `wp search-replace`

Or else for mysql use the replace function like so:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'old', 'new');
```

You potentially want to also update the posts GUID column

Also don't forget about changing the wp_options siteurl and home values